# Should a king be restrict to marry a queen that is also a philosopher in Plato's point of view?

Tags: political-philosophy, plato

Should a king be restrict to marry a queen that is also a philosopher in Plato's point of view?

I know that the king had big power and should be a philosopher in Plato's view. If the queen have some power also, must she also be a philosopher too?

Comment: If one member of a couple is a philosopher, perhaps the other one should be a stenographer. Otherwise they'd spend all their time talking to each other and never write anything down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Republic Plato claimed that the idea of marriage was a "natural enemy" of the "commonwealth," aiming for its own higher unity. He thinks that a king should not marry nor should he engage in sexual conduct while he is king, as it is a distraction from the 24/7 job of ruling, and to lack the wisdom and self-control necessary to avoid sexual temptation is unbecoming of a man who holds the highest of stations. I dont believe he mentions queens and in his view they would be unnecessary, yet he doesnt explicitly discount the possibility of the rule of a sole unmarried philosopher queen. He does speak of a kind of eugenics where temporary marriages are arranged by the rulers, and an allowance of  promiscuity at retirement as a reward for a lifetime of service to the republic.